# pandas parse dates from csv

Tags: parsing, datetime, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file which includes dates. The csv looks like this:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5
A,B,C,D,E,20150420
A,B,C,D,E,20150420
A,B,C,D,E,20150420
```

For reading the csv I use this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filen,
    index_col=None,
    header=0,
    parse_dates=[5],
    date_parser=lambda t:parse(t))
```

The parse function looks like this:

```
def parse(t):
    string_ = str(t)
    try:
        return datetime.date(int(string_[:4]), int(string_[4:6]), int(string_[6:]))
    except:
        return datetime.date(1900,1,1)
```

My strange problem now is that in the parsing function, `t` looks like this:

```
ndarray: ['20150420' '20150420' '20150420']
```

As you can see `t` is the whole array of the data column. I think it should be only the first value when parsing the first row, the second value, when parsing the second row, etc. Right now, the `parse` always ends up in the except-block because `int(string_[:4])` contains a bracket, which, obviously, cannot be converted to an int. The parse function is built to parse only one date at a time (e.g. `20150420`) in the first place.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

okay, I just read in the pandas doc about the [date_parser](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) argument, and it seems to work as expected (of course ;)). So I need to adapt my code to that. My above example is copy&pasted from somewhere else and I expected it to work, hence, my question.. I will report back, when I did my code adaption.

**EDIT2:**

My parse function now looks like this, and I think, the code works now. If I am still doing something wrong, please let me know:

```
def parse(t):
    ret = []
    for ts in t:
        string_ = str(ts)
        try:
            tsdt = datetime.date(int(string_[:4]), int(string_[4:6]), int(string_[6:]))
        except:
            tsdt = datetime.date(1900,1,1)
        ret.append(tsdt)
    return ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are six columns, but only five titles in the first line. This is why `parse_dates` failed. you can skip the first line:

```
df = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv",  header=None, skiprows=1, parse_dates=[5])
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this parser  :

```
parser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d', coerce=True)
```

and use

```
df = pd.read_csv(filen,
index_col=None,
header=0,
parse_dates=[5],
date_parser=parser)
```